# how to save as mp3 or wav file in python in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, text-to-speech, mobile-application

i have created a project text to speech in python kivy, i want to save the converted speech file as .mp3 or .wav file. i tried but i cannot save as audio file.

here, i don't know how to save the converted speech as audio file

## text to speech function pyttsx3

```
def say_something(self, text):
    try:
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.setProperty('rate', 160)
        engine.setProperty('volume', 0.9)
        text1 = engine.say(text)
        engine.save_to_file(text, 'text_input.mp3')
        engine.runAndWait()
```

#save function

```
def show_save(self):
    content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
    self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                        size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
    self._popup.open()

def save(self, path, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as stream:
        stream.write(self.text1)
    self.dismiss_popup()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.
have you tried this? https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
myobj=gTTS(text=mytext,lang=language,slow=True)
myobj.save("welcome1.mp3")
```

Hope this is useful.